# Yii 1.1 Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, yii

This may look like a duplicate but I did some research and tried them all. I'm still getting this error.

I changed the memory_limit to -1 and 536870912, and the result is the same.

I also used php -i to locate the php.ini to confirm if I am editing the correct file.

Comment: And yes, I also restarted the apache many times. Every changes i made, i always restart it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have some endless loop somewhere. Since it tries to allocate only 72 bytes and exhausts the 536870912 it looks like an endless loop.

Comment: I'm not sure to that. I tried to test it on our local machine, with the same php ini and code. It works successfully.

Comment: You could also try adding ini_set("memory_limit","512M"); to public/index.php just for the debugging purpose. This way you can see if maybe it's still the wrong config file.